# jQuery UI datepicker dropdown focus "jumping" in chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When in jQuery UI datepicker I added year or month dropdowns and when I open them and hover mouse over different item, the focus jums back to the one which was chosen by default it - for example if default month on datepicker when its opened is September, and I open dropdown and hover over january, it highlights it, but quickly goes back at September. I Tested with Chrome, IE and FF and it happens only in chrome.

```
$(function() {
  $('#date').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: 'c-100',
  });
});
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery and jQueryUI and which browser versions are you having problems with?

Comment: jquery-1.8.0
jquery-ui-1.8.23
Chrome 21(up-2-date)

Comment: @EverWondeR I have the exact problem! my chrome version is 21.0 and no problem in IE or Firefox. also I added my content through pure javascript but have the same problem. could you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too

```
                $(function() {
                    $('#date').datepicker({
                      changeMonth: true,
                      changeYear: true,
                      yearRange: 'c-100',
                      onSelect: function (date) {
                     $(this).focus();
                     });
                  });
```

try adding  `$(this).focus();`

Comment: Now I can't even open datepicker :(